# Adding Menu, Social Media, and custom line into header

Tags: menu, navigation

I am trying to customize my header to look more like the header on this site http://makingmagique.com. I love that it is fixed and translucent. Also love that the menu is next to the "logo" and the social media buttons are all on the right side. Bonus points if you can figure out how to add a custom line at the bottom. ;) Any idea how to do this? I am currently on a Twenty Twelve Wordpress but am open to other themes.

Anyone know how to customize a header like this? My site is http://beyondblessedblog.com.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your relevant code with what your header is now and where you fail to look like the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the relevant pieces of the header (I copied them directly from makingmagique.com). If you aren't already, you should get familiar with your browser's [developer](https://getfirebug.com/faq/) [tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="site-title">
            ... <!-- title/logo -->
        </h1>

        <div id="after-header">
            <div class="menu-container" id="primary-menu">
                ... <!-- navigation menus -->
            </div>

            <div class="search" id="search-1">
                ... <!-- search box -->
            </div>

            <div id="social">
                ... <!-- social links -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>  <!-- this is the colored line at the bottom -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-container {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}
#header {
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  width: 1020px;
}

/* title/logo */
#site-title {
  float: left;
  height: 41px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 265px;
  z-index: 300;
}

#after-header {
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 26px;
  width: 695px;
}

/* navigation menus */
#primary-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

/* search box */
#after-header .search {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: normal;
}

/* social links */
#social {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

/* this is the colored line at the bottom */
.divider {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c6e0e5 0%, #ffcdce 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

P.S. the menu animations and hover states are [another kettle of fish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).